# What is the difference between doing `context.canvas.width` and `canvas.width`?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

When working with the HTML5 element **Canvas**, what is the difference between doing `context.canvas.width` and `canvas.width`? Likewise with `... .height`.

Comment: There is no difference as `context.canvas` is the same object as `canvas` eg `console.log(context.canvas === canvas); // >> true` assuming you created the `content` from `canvas`  eg `context = canvas.getContext("2d");` Or using the lingo, `context.canvas`, and `canvas` both *reference* the same *object*

Comment: @Blindman67 Would you mind writing this up as an answer and I'll mark my question as completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two names one referenced object

There is no difference as `context.canvas` is the same object as `canvas` assuming you created the context from the canvas.

```
// They are the same when the strict equality is true.
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(context.canvas === canvas); // >> true
```

The variable `context` references a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) with the property [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/canvas) that references the [`HTMLCanvasElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), named `canvas`, used to get `context` via the call [`HTMLCanvasElement.getContext("2d")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext)